# Update/Deploy Sideloaded Windows Store App Remotely?

Tags: deployment, windows-8, windows-store-apps, sideloading

We're about to start developing a modern app (LOB) for Windows 8. I've researched how to deploy it via powershell and what I need to do to enable sideloading, etc.

My question is about the administrative process of this. Is it possible to do this remotely? If we have, say 15 devices that this app will be used on, do we need to go to each one and run the powershell script to update it?

It doesn't seem like the `add-appxpackage` command has any parameters to execute against a remote machine, though I might be missing something.

I've seen a few references to using System Center to do this? Is that my only option?

Comment: Tim, Did you find out answer for your question? If so please share it. I am looking for options to sideload remotely

Comment: Yes System Center is the way to do that. Or MS Intune, which is a monthly subscription per device.